# How can I Find user that has most orders (include user data) using C# EF and Linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have an assignment, I have to find the User that has most orders (including user data).
Here is my database diagram.[[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W60pZ.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewog2.png)

Here is an example of getting most sold product(not included in the question):

```
var productsGroup = orders.GroupBy(x => x.Product)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.Count).Sum());

var mostSoldProduct = productsGroup.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value).Key;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, Can you show your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow editor now has a feature that allows you to use tables. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: You post a requirement and code, but not a question. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I got from your question and the images you have attached, a linq query like this should work (*notice that I assume the `DbContext` instance is `_dbContext`*) :

```
_dbContext.OrderData.GroupBy(orderData => orderData.UserId)
.Select(g => new
{
    UserId = g.Key,
    MaxNumberOfOrders = g.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.MaxNumberOfOrders).FirstOrDefault();
```

This linq query results :

```
SELECT TOP(1) [o].[UserId], COUNT(*) AS [MaxNumberOfOrders]
FROM [OrderData] AS [o]
GROUP BY [o].[UserId]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Which gives you the `userId` with the most orders and the number of orders.